# Querying multiple values

Tags: aws-cli, jmespath

I'm trying to filter by multiple values however I can't seem to get an and clause to work (e.g. filter1 and filter 2 ... etc.):

Show me snapshots where the database name is 'testing'

```
aws rds describe-db-snapshots --include-shared --query 'DBSnapshots[?DBInstanceIdentifier==`testing`].{DBNAME:DBInstanceIdentifier,SNAPSHOT:DBSnapshotIdentifier}'
[
    {
        "SNAPSHOT": "test1",
        "DBNAME": "testing"
    },
    {
        "SNAPSHOT": "test2",
        "DBNAME": "testing"
    },
    {
        "SNAPSHOT": "test3",
        "DBNAME": "testing"
    },
    {
        "SNAPSHOT": "test4",
        "DBNAME": "testing"
    }
]
```

Show me snapshots named 'test1'

```
$ aws rds describe-db-snapshots --include-shared --query 'DBSnapshots[?DBSnapshotIdentifier==`test1`].{DBNAME:DBInstanceIdentifier,SNAPSHOT:DBSnapshotIdentifier}'
[
    {
        "SNAPSHOT": "test1",
        "DBNAME": "testing"
    },
        {
        "SNAPSHOT": "test1",
        "DBNAME": "testing2"
    }
]
```

Show me snapshots from the database testing that are named test1

```
aws rds describe-db-snapshots --include-shared --query 'DBSnapshots[?DBInstanceIdentifier==`testing`][?DBSnapshotIdentifier==`test1`].{DBNAME:DBInstanceIdentifier,SNAPSHOT:DBSnapshotIdentifier}'
[]
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to work with the [`AND` expression](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#and-expressions) so something like this will make the trick

```
$ aws rds describe-db-snapshots --include-shared \
--query 'DBSnapshots[?(DBInstanceIdentifier==`testing` && DBSnapshotIdentifier==`test1`)].{DBNAME:DBInstanceIdentifier,SNAPSHOT:DBSnapshotIdentifier}'
```

Comment: I actually needed the && expression not  || to return what I want. The link provided is much better than anything I found. Thanks. My final solution is: aws rds describe-db-snapshots --include-shared --query 'DBSnapshots[?DBInstanceIdentifier==`testing` && DBSnapshotIdentifier==`test1`].{DBNAME:DBInstanceIdentifier,SNAPSHOT:DBSnapshotIdentifier}'   I've submitted an edit to your answer to reflect this. Once it gets approved I'll accept your response as answer.

Comment: sorry, I misread the initial question and thought you wanted one or the other , thanks for the edit and the correction