# AWS CLI How to Query Multiple Arguments from the same element?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm trying to use AWS CLI to query S3 objects owned by a specific account AND only if the object has a specific size. Is there any way to do an AND query? These are some of the hundreds of alternatives I've already tried but none of them worked:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket bucket-name --fetch-owner  --output json --query "'Contents[?Size==`0`].[Key,Owner.ID,Size]' || [?Owner.ID=='00000000111111122222222aaabbbcccdddeeefff']"
```

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket bucket-name --fetch-owner --output json --query "Contents[?Owner.ID=='00000000111111122222222aaabbbcccdddeeefff']||[?Size==`0`].[Key,Size]"
```

Any help is welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47163478/querying-multiple-values and if so did this help?

Comment: Excellent. Now answer your own question with what you've learned. :)

Comment: @Uberhumus that certainly helped! I couldn't find it, many thanks.
For future references, this is the final command: 

> aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket bucket-name --fetch-owner --output json --query 'Contents[?(Owner.ID==`00000000111111122222222aaabbbcccdddeeefff` && Size==0)].[Key,Size,Owner.ID]'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For future references, this is the final command:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket bucket-name --fetch-owner --output json --query 'Contents[?(Owner.ID==`00000000111111122222222aaabbbcccdddeeefff` && Size==`0`)].[Key,Size,Owner.ID]'
```

Thanks a lot @Uberhumus